# What TypeScript type is used to pass a class in Vue 3 script setup prop definitions?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-sfc, vue-script-setup

I have a Vue 3 single file component using the [script setup](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html) approach. One of the props I want to define will be accepting the equivalent of the `class` attribute. This means the prop value could be a string, an expression, an array, or object. The problem comes when I try to use `withDefaults()` to assign a default empty string value to this prop.

```js
withDefaults(
  defineProps<{
    itemClass?: unknown
  }>(),
  {
    itemClass: '',
  }
)
```

Which is bound as

```html
<div :class="itemClass">...</div>
```

I'm trying to avoid using `any` as the type. I tried `unknown` but get an error when I try to give it a default value. The temporary solution seems to be to simply remove the default value, but there may be cases where I want a default value set.

Is there a specific type for the Vue `class` attribute?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `class` binding value can be one of the following types:

- `string`

  *Example:*

  ```html
  <div :class="myStringProp">
  ```
- `Record<string, boolean>` ([Object syntax](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/class-and-style.html#object-syntax))

  *Example:*

  ```html
  <div :class="{ active: true, error: true }">
  ```

or a mixed array of the above:

- `(string | Record<string, boolean>)[]` ([Array syntax](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/class-and-style.html#array-syntax))

  *Example:*

  ```html
  <div :class="['item', { active: true, error: true }]">
  ```

So the `itemClass` type should be the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of these types:

```js
defineProps<{
  itemClass?: string | Record<string, boolean> | (string | Record<string, boolean>)[]
}>()
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-type-for-class-prop?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FMyLabel.vue)

Answer (score 3):

With Vue 3.2.39 I use this:

```
  import { HTMLAttributes } from "vue";

  const props = defineProps<{
    class?: HTMLAttributes["class"];
  }>();
```

Anyway it is still `any`. Hope Vue will have proper types soon.